# "Type 'lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult' cannot be serialized"

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I am using lxml to extract data from web pages, but I am unable to convert the resulting ElementUnicode object to a string. Here is my code:

```
from lxml import html
from lxml import etree
from lxml.etree import tostring

url = 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5848272/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=2413b25e-e3f6-4229-9efd-599bb9ab1f97&pf_rd_r=9S5A89ZHEXE4K8SZBC40&pf_rd_s=right-2&pf_rd_t=15061&pf_rd_i=homepage&ref_=hm_otw_t0'

page = requests.get('url')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

a = tree.xpath('//div[@class="credit_summary_item"]/a[../h4/text() = "Directors:"]/text()')
mynewlist = []
for i in a:
  b = etree.tostring(i, method="text")
  mynewlist.append(b)
```

Here is the error I get:

```
TypeError: Type 'lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult' cannot be serialized.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you give us the xml file you're parsing? In my experience `tree.xpath('//path/text()')` should output a list of strings so what you're doing next is a little weird to me

Comment: I'm scraping from web pages so no XML, I was under the impression that lxml could do that.

Comment: Then an example HTML which reproduces the problem; this is the idea of a minimal working example: we must be able to run the code

Comment: Yes, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I edited the question with the URL link I'm working on and the XPath query.

Comment: A small complaint: you did not provide a complete MCVE. `import requests` is missing and `requests.get('url')` should be `requests.get(url)`. Please always test run the code before posting.

Comment: @mzjn Sorry for the inconvenience, duly noted for next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `i` variable is an [`_ElementUnicodeResult`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult-class.html) object (a special type of string). You cannot use it as an argument to [`tostring()`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#tostring).

The `a` variable (the result of the XPath evaluation) is the list of strings that you want. If the elements of this list must be plain strings instead of `_ElementUnicodeResult` objects, you can use a list comprehension:

```
newlist = [str(s) for s in a]
```

Comment: The problem is that the resulting list is composed of _ElementUnicodeResult strings; I am trying to convert these to plain strings.

Comment: `newlist = [str(s) for s in a]` should do it.

Answer (score 4):

I too had trouble converting `'lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult'` to string.

Then i found the following link.

https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult-class.html

You can see that `_ElementUnicodeResult` has inherited a  lot of functions from `unicode`.

I used `__str__()` function, which converted it to string type.

It also supports a number of other string operations directly. You can check in the link. Hope this helps ;)

Comment: How did you use it? `foo.__str__()` does not work :/

Comment: check what error you are getting. For me actually the isssue was that, a local variable had name `str` , so my str function wasnt getting called.
Try the other solutions, and check with specific to the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

```
text = ''.join([str(s) for s in elementUnicodeResult])
```